# what is a GR image?

Tags: matlab, rgb, matlab-coder, gray-code

My teacher has assigned me to work combine RGB channels and create a GR image, whose results are like a negative image as shown here:

[image: GRimage]

I have tried the following code:

```py
GR1=(double(100*green_channel/1+red_channel+blue_channel));
GR2=(double(256/1+red_channel+blue_channel+green_channel));
GR=(double(GR1.*GR2));
```

But this does not produce the desired results.

Comment: Why aren't these results "desired"?

Comment: @Adriaan because its pure white and the result shall be as in picture uploaded

Answer (score 1):

I assume the main issue is the lack of parentheses in the denominator of your `GR1` and `GR2` equations.  For example, I assume you want something like `GR2=double(256/(1+red_channel+blue_channel+green_channel));`

Secondarily, how did you display the image?  Look at the min and max values of `GR` and verify that they are compatible with the function you are using.  The min and max could also likely have tipped you off to the parentheses issue.